# Conditional formatting custom forumla for comparing value to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a row (31) that contains various numerical values e.g: 1,000 or 25,000

I have a cell (H7) that contains a value e.g 20,000

I want to set a custom formula so that when any value in Row 31 is equal or greater than the value in cell H7, the cells turn green.

I can't work out how to test the formatting against the whole of row 31.

I know I can do the comparison with `>=$H7` but how do I do this against row 31/the full range of the conditional formatting?

Comment: You can use this formula for conditional formatting: **=OR(A$31>$H$7,A$31=$H$7)**

Answer (score 1):

Set up your rule on the first cell on the row, then change the Applies To value to be the entire row.

[image]

My example looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula for conditional formatting:

```
=OR(A$31>$H$7,A$31=$H$7)
```

[image]